# Microsoft Intune - How to modify Windows 10 registry settings?

Tags: windows-registry, batch, microsoft-intune

Win32 app uses bat file to install software and edit registry keys. Registry keys are modified if I run bat file locally but not when run through via Intune because Intune runs installation as System.

I created a PowerShell script that works when run locally but if I use Intune registry keys are not modified.

How can I edit registry keys via Intune?

Intune PowerShell scripts
`Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name 'AutoAdminLogon' -Value 0`

Win32 app bat file
`reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "AutoAdminLogon" /t REG_SZ /d "" /f`

Comment: can you provide a sample of PS code, which doesn't work?

Comment: @batistuta09 `Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name 'AutoAdminLogon' -Value 0`

Comment: By default Intune use 32 bit PowerShell. Locally I use 64 bit PS. I tried 32 bit PS and no error was given but registry was not modified. I'll try to use 64 bit PS in Intune.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name "AutoAdminLogon" -PropertyType "DWORD" -Value "0" -Force
```

Comment: You have to select "Run script in 64 bit PowerShell host". Intune's default setting is 32 bit PowerShell host.